%~s1 and %~fs1 difference in batch script?
In this batch script, both %~s1 and %~fs1 output D:\THISIS~1\USERSB~1:
@echo off
set "HOME_DIR=D:\ThisIsBatchDirectoryWithLongPath\UsersBatchSubdirectory"

call :Method %HOME_DIR%

exit /b

:Method
echo %~s1
echo %~fs1

rem for %%i in (%~1) do (
rem     echo %%~si
rem     echo %%~fsi
rem )

exit /b


What’s the difference between them?
How can you demonstrate this difference in a batch script?


MS docs for “for” You can get help at the command-line by typing for /? or help for. The s gives you short names — i.e. filenames with generated 8.5 format. fs expands to a full path using only short names.

What about adding another call? e.g. call :Method "%HOME_DIR:*\=%". This should pass the argument "ThisIsBatchDirectoryWithLongPath\UsersBatchSubdirectory", rather than D:\ThisIsBatchDirectoryWithLongPath\UsersBatchSubdirectory, and may show a difference.

I would also say that your example code should read as call :Method "%HOME_DIR%", and rem for %%i in ("%~1") do (.

I've tried it, it doesn't look much different.

There is NO difference between %~s1 and %~fs1 .
There can be executed in a command prompt window call /? to output the usage help of command CALL which explains the modifiers of batch file arguments.

   %~f1        - expands %1 to a fully qualified path name
   %~d1        - expands %1 to a drive letter only
   %~p1        - expands %1 to a path only
   %~n1        - expands %1 to a file name only
   %~x1        - expands %1 to a file extension only
   %~s1        - expanded path contains short names only
   %~a1        - expands %1 to file attributes
   %~t1        - expands %1 to date/time of file
   %~z1        - expands %1 to size of file
   %~$PATH:1   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                  environment variable and expands %1 to the fully
                  qualified name of the first one found.  If the
                  environment variable name is not defined or the
                  file is not found by the search, then this
                  modifier expands to the empty string

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

   %~dp1       - expands %1 to a drive letter and path only
   %~nx1       - expands %1 to a file name and extension only
   %~dp$PATH:1 - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                  environment variable for %1 and expands to the
                  drive letter and path of the first one found.
   %~ftza1     - expands %1 to a DIR like output line```


The modifier f is for referencing the file/folder with the fully qualified file/folder name as stored by the file system in long format if the file/folder exists at all which means with drive + path + name + extension. The expansion to fully qualified file name is done by cmd.exe even on file/folder does not exist in file system. That can be used to get the full name of a file/folder specified with a relative path to current working directory even if the referenced file/folder does not yet exist in file system.
The modifier s is for referencing the file/folder with the file/folder name as stored by the file system in short 8.3 format if the file/folder exists at all. Please read below for more details about the short modifier s.
The same modifiers can be used on referencing a FOR loop variable as it can be read in the output usage help on running for /? in a command prompt window.
Here is an example:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FolderName=%TEMP%\ThisIsBatchDirectoryWithLongPath\Users Batch Subdirectory.directory"
for %%I in ("%FolderName%\..") do md "%%~fI" 2>nul
rd "%FolderName%" 2>nul
set "CreateDirectory=1"
:Demo
echo(
if exist "%FolderName%" (echo With existing directory:) else echo With not existing directory:
echo(
for %%I in ("%FolderName%") do (
    echo ~fI:   %%~fI
    echo ~sI:   %%~sI
    echo ~fsI:  %%~fsI
    echo ~sfI:  %%~sfI
    echo ~dpI:  %%~dpI
    echo ~dpsI: %%~dpsI
    echo ~sdpI: %%~sdpI
    echo ~nxsI: %%~nxsI
    echo ~snxI: %%~snxI
    echo ~nsxI: %%~nsxI
    echo ~nsI:  %%~nsI
    echo ~snI:  %%~snI
    echo ~xsI:  %%~xsI
    echo ~sxI:  %%~sxI
)
if defined CreateDirectory md "%FolderName%" && (set "CreateDirectory=" & goto Demo)
rd "%FolderName%" 2>nul
for %%I in ("%FolderName%\..") do rd "%%~fI"
echo(
endlocal
pause

The output is:
With not existing directory:

~fI:   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ThisIsBatchDirectoryWithLongPath\Users Batch Subdirectory.directory
~sI:   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\THISIS~1\Users Batch Subdirectory.directory
~fsI:  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\THISIS~1\Users Batch Subdirectory.directory
~sfI:  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\THISIS~1\Users Batch Subdirectory.directory
~dpI:  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ThisIsBatchDirectoryWithLongPath\
~dpsI: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\THISIS~1\
~sdpI: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\THISIS~1\
~nxsI: Users Batch Subdirectory.directory
~snxI: Users Batch Subdirectory.directory
~nsxI: Users Batch Subdirectory.directory
~nsI:  Users Batch Subdirectory
~snI:  Users Batch Subdirectory
~xsI:  .directory
~sxI:  .directory

With existing directory:

~fI:   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ThisIsBatchDirectoryWithLongPath\Users Batch Subdirectory.directory
~sI:   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\THISIS~1\USERSB~1.DIR
~fsI:  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\THISIS~1\USERSB~1.DIR
~sfI:  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\THISIS~1\USERSB~1.DIR
~dpI:  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ThisIsBatchDirectoryWithLongPath\
~dpsI: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\THISIS~1\
~sdpI: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\THISIS~1\
~nxsI: USERSB~1.DIR
~snxI: USERSB~1.DIR
~nsxI: USERSB~1.DIR
~nsI:  USERSB~1
~snI:  USERSB~1
~xsI:  .DIR
~sxI:  .DIR

Press any key to continue . . .

This example shows:

It makes no difference if in addition to modifier s is used also the modifier f before or after modifier s. The modifier s alone returns the full short 8.3 name of the directory/file.
The directory or file must really exist on using modifier s. That is a difference to the other directory/file name modifiers like d, n, p, x and f where the file system is also accessed on expansion, but the directory/file name must not exist to get its parts or its full name. The short 8.3 name is defined by the file system and only the file system can return it.
It is possible to configure that the file system does not create short 8.3 names for each directory/file. There is returned on usage of modifier s the long directory/file name if this feature is disabled and no short 8.3 name exists for a file or directory.
The demo shows further that the short 8.3 name is used for those parts of the full directory/file name for which a short 8.3 name exists while the long name is used for the parts for which no short 8.3 name exists as not created by the file system.
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp is not completely in uppercase because of no short 8.3 name exists for those directories.
For directory ThisIsBatchDirectoryWithLongPath created first exists the short 8.3 name THISIS~1 which is used even if the subdirectory Users Batch Subdirectory.directory does not exist.
It does not matter where the modifier s is specified in the list of modifiers on combining this modifier with other modifiers like n and/or x. It is advisable to have modifier s always left to the loop variable for easier seeing it on looking on the command lines.

Read also the Microsoft documentation about Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces. There can be used the real full long name of a directory or file with \\.\ at the beginning to pass the directory/file name directly to the file system which bypasses also the MAX_PATH limitation of cmd.exe and its internal commands.
MAX_PATH is defined with 260 characters, i.e. 259 characters for directory/file name with full path plus a string terminating null byte. The maximum length of a file name is 256 characters on being stored in the root directory of a drive which requires three characters for referencing it (drive letter, colon, backslash) and the file should be accessible with MAX_PATH length limitation. Each directory name in path of a file reduces the maximum file name length if MAX_PATH length limitation should not be exceeded for avoiding troubles on processing the file as many applications are coded with MAX_PATH length limitation.
There is additionally the command prompt (Cmd.exe) command-line string limitation with 8191 characters (8192 with string terminating null byte). In a batch file cannot be processed directories and files of which fully qualified name is longer than 8191 characters. The maximum length of directory/file names is reduced even more depending on the command line like enclosing the fully qualified name in " because of containing a space or one of these characters &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~.
